# UITableView dynamic cell height scroll to top after calling reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have dynamic cell height in my tableView

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

I want to do same as whatsapp app (pagination), i want to load 25 by 25 row so when user scroll at top, i want to load new data but i want to keep same position of scroll, here is what i did

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if isMore && scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
         loadMore() // function that add new data in my model
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The problem that i have is after i reach top of my tableview it call reloadData but the tableView scroll to UP

I tester some other solution like this:

```
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let height = cellHeights[indexPath] else { return 70.0 }
    return height
}
```

But still not working

Comment: By default, `.reloadData()` on a table view does **NOT** change the scroll position of the table. Maybe something else in your `loadMore()` or some other function is changing the table view properties?

Comment: yes cause i use dynamic cell height UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Hmmm... You say *"when user scroll at top, i want to load new data"* ... So you want to add new rows above row zero?

Comment: Do you mean like in Whatsapp, when you scroll up in a chat and it loads older messages?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Comment: @OuSS - I'm not clear on your "scroll at top" or "scroll up" ... Do you mean, for example, that there is a total of 100 items of data. You are currently showing items 75 to 100. If the user pulls down the table (so row 75 is at the top), you want to retrieve items 50 to 74 but have row 75 still at the top of the table?

Comment: I want to do same as whatsapp chat, the recent message are at bottom, the old one are at top, first load i will show 25 messages and when user scroll at indexPath.row == 0 i will load other 25 messages, the problem is when i get the second 25 messages and i call reloadData it redraw the tableview with 50 messages and i have the scroll at row == 0 cause im using dynamic cell height, it should keep same scroll before reloadData that what i want

Comment: OK - I understand what you're trying to do (not everyone uses every app, so it's best to describe your issue rather than saying "like that other app"). Are you sure your problem is due to dynamic cell height? Do you have the functionality working just like you want when using fixed-height cells? Your task *may* work better using a CollectionView with a custom layout, or maybe just using a scroll view.

Comment: I just tested with fix height, it seems have same problem, i need to use uitableview cause i dont have only text to show, also images and button ..

Comment: OK - so it sounds like it's *not* because of the dynamic row heights. `UITableView` is hardly your only option though... `UICollectionView` does pretty much everything a table view does, and is much more flexible. Something to keep in mind... the app you are trying to emulate - WhatsApp - has a pretty big development team. It is very possible that you will need to write some very customized code to get that to work the way you want... just dropping in a table view and calling reloadData() might not do the job.

Comment: ok, and why i need to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView ? i will not face same problem ??

Comment: I'm not saying that you ***need*** to use collection view... I'm saying you might ***want*** to. With collection view, you can subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and get it to behave exactly how you want, which might make "inserting items above the current top item" easier and smoother.

Comment: @OuSS: Did you try the answer I posted? Or came up with anything better?

Comment: No i used DGElasticPullToRefresh, when i drag tableview i load new rows at top and i scrollToRow

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the table to add more data , then after reload call below function to retain the scroll position.

```
tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
```

here indexPath is the indexPath of the last cell before reload.

Comment: this function doesnt keep the exact same position

Comment: can you try by changing the UITableViewScrollPosition?

Comment: How i get the position ?

Comment: UITableViewScrollPosition is an enum. Instead of .middle you can change to .bottom or .top

Comment: I did but it doesnt keep the exact position of scroll before updating, check whatsapp scroliing when they load new data is smouth and it doesnt stop scrolling

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:cellForRowAt` when you detect `indexPath` is getting close to the last element (when `indexPath.row` is getting close to `yourArray.count`), query for more items. When you have them, add them to your data source (the array, or whatever it is, where you have all the objects represented in the table) and reload the table view. The table view should display the new items and the user can continue scrolling without doing anything special.

You shouldn't wait until `tableView:cellForRowAt` is called for the last cell, as the user will have to wait if you need to call a server to fetch more items. Whatsapp's scroll is fast because they download the items well before you scroll to the last elements (some time ago it did stop at the end, but now they are probably fetching new items way earlier).

Keep in mind that 25 items might be too few, it the network is slow the user might scroll through the items you have before more items to display and will have to wait, which is not a good user experience. Simulate a slow network connection and see if 25 items are enough to scroll through while your app contacts the server (depends on network speed, request and response sizes, how fast the server answers your request, etc.).

Comment: Is all what i did just im testing on indexPath.row == 0 cause i want to load data at top not bottom like whatsapp but the problem is cause i have dynamic cell height 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension' when i call reloadData of tableview, the position of the scroll is always at row = 0 like it redraw the table

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in a messaging App. Here's how I solved it:

1. Assigned an unique `messageId` to every **message** in datasource array.
2. In `cellForRow:`, I save that `messageId` of very first row in a variable called `messageIdFirst`.

   ```
   if(indexPath.row == 0){
       messageIdFirst = message.id!
   }
   ```
3. In `loadMore()` method, I check which current **indexpath** row have the same **messageId** in now updated datasource array.

   ```
   if(message.id == messageIdFirst){
       previousTopIndexPath = i
   }
   ```

   *,where i being that index in datasource array which have the same `messageId.`*
4. Now, I scroll to that `previousTopIndexPath` like this:

   `tableview.scrollToRow(at: previousTopIndexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)`

**Note 1**: As this was not working efficiently in `UITableView`, I end up using `UICollectionView` with the same solution.

**Note 2:** While this does work smoothly, I know there must exist a cleaner way to do this.